# how to auto populate dropdown without having 'id' field in cakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I have two tables:

1. countries with fields [objid(PK), name]
2. cities with fields [objid(PK), name, country_id(FK)]

Using cakePHP, what would be the correct syntax of using $belongsTo in city model to auto populate the countries drop down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**City Model**

```
  class City extends AppModel{
       var name = "City";
        var $primaryKey = "objid";
       var $belongsTo = array('Country' =>  array('className' => 'Country','foreignKey' =>'country_id'));
    }
```

**County Model**

```
class Country extends AppModel{
    var name = "Country";
    var $primaryKey = "objid";
    var $hasMany = array('City');
}
```